# Passing value from java to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

I'm making an Android app using webview.
The app can print out receipts. What I want to do is when the printer is not working, alert box shows up to tell the printer isn't working, and return false to the form's onsubmit event to prevent form from being submitted.

Java code:

```
public class JSKicker {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void callPrint(final String argumet) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                int nRtn;
                connectionNum = myPrinter.Connect("000.000.0.000");

                if(connectionNum < 0){ //Printer not working

                 webview.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String script = "alert('Printer Error'); return printer_connection = false;";
                            webview.evaluateJavascript(script, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                                @Override
                                // I can't figure out what to do here...
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }else{ //Printer is working properly
                    connectionNum = myPrinter.SetLocale(8);
                    strText = argument;
                    nRtn = myPrinter.PrintText(strText, "SJIS");

                    nRtn = myPrinter.PaperFeed(64);
                    nRtn = myPrinter.CutPaper(1);

                    myPrinter.Disconnect();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

JavaScript in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gate(){
        jQuery.ajax({
                    url:'/cart_info.php',
                    type:'GET'
                })
                .done( (data) => {
                    window.JSKicker.callPrint(data);
                })

                if (printer_connection = false) {
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
    }

</script>
```

HTML form tag:

```
<form method="post" id="order_form" onsubmit="return gate();">
```

How can I get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do it thru WebView.evaluateJavascript()?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)

So with that you could send simple CustomEvent to document in WebView

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("document.dispatchEvent(new Event('printer_error', { details: "No printer found!" }));");
```

and in JavaScript you can hook listener for your custom event to react.

```
document.addEventListener('printer_error', e => alert(e.details));
```

Didn't test this so might be that at least evaluateJavascript() needs callback function.

Comment: I could use evaluateJavascript() to show alert box from Java!
Is it possible to send something to JS to make the form from submitting??
I made some change to my code.

Comment: With that same approach you can do what ever actions in your page. E.g. document.addEventListener('submit_form', e => document.getElementById('my-form').submit()) would be simplest way. Check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket can solve your problem.

WebSockets provide a persistent connection between a client and server that both parties can use to start sending data at any time. The client establishes a WebSocket connection through a process known as the WebSocket handshake.

Its very straight forward and easy to implement.

You can follow referrer links for more details:-

JAVA WebSocket:- [WebSocket using Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets), [WebSocket using Simple JEE](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#section7)

Browser WebSocket(JavaScript):- [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)

Answer (score 0):

In Android ,if you want webview pass value to JavaScript.
First,you need to set the webview enable the JavaScript,

```
    private WebView mWebView;

    void onCreate(){
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    }
```

And ,in you want do some thing code

```
if(connectionNum < 0){ //Printer not working
// I need to do something here to send a message that the printer isn't working to JS.
//In thread can not use mWebView,should send message to MainThread to do
     // mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:javaCall()");
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = 1;
        myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    //myHandler can be your MainThread send to here
}
```

And where the mWebView created in your code, be in main thread ,you can use the
Handler to deal with the message sended to here.

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
  @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
      // this 1 is just thread send to here
      if (msg.what == 1) {
         //and here can do the webview UI method
         mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:javaCall()");
      }
  }
```

};

the javaCall() is where you JacaScript invoke method,in javaScript you can writre like this:

```
<script language="javascript">  
function javaCall(){  
    alert("Printer Error");
    //other thing you can do
}  
</script>
```

if you have problem ,you can refer to the official document.

```
public void loadUrl (String url)
Loads the given URL.
Also see compatibility note on evaluateJavascript(String, ValueCallback).
```

[webview use link](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Comment: I tried and it's giving an error, saying;
    E: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-22528
    Process: com.my_web.new_project, PID: 9186
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-22528'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread..etc
 Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-22528'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {36b83ccf} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {36b83ccf})

Comment: I got that ,your code is in thread to  notificaton the next thing.So you can use Handler to solve this error. I will edit the answer.

Comment: There's an error on 'sendMessage' saying 'Non-static method 'sendMessage(android.os.Message)' cannot be referenced from a static context' :(
I coudn't find out how to fix this